# Evaluating a limit as $x \to -\infty$ of a power of a rational function

Tags: limits, exponentiation, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

Sorry for the weird title, I don't know how to put the equation on the title.

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{1-x^3}{x^2+7x}\right)^5$$

Ok I divided inside the parenthesis by $x^2$, but now I am stuck.

Comment: You'd be better off dividing by $x^3$ inside the parantheses.

Comment: I got -1/0 for the answer??

Comment: Can I use L'hospital's rule?

Comment: no we are not allowed to use that rule yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we divide numerator and denominator in the parentheses by $x^3$ we get

$$\frac{1-x^3}{x^2+7x}=\frac{ 1/x^3 - 1}{1/x + 7/x^2}$$

Now note that as $x\to -\infty$ the numerator approaches $-1$ and the denominator approaches $0$. So overall the fraction diverges.
This already shows that the original limit diverges since the exponential function is continuous.

Answer (score -1):

Since $X^5$ is continuous, it suffice to calculate $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{1-x^3}{x^2+7x}\right)$$. Then by using L'Hospital's rule twice, you get the answer $\infty$.

Without using LHospital's rule, divide $x^2$ on the numerator and denominator.
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-x}{1+\frac{7}{x}}\right)$$

As $x\to -\infty$, $\frac{1}{x^2}\to 0, \frac{1}{x}\to 0$, hence numerator $\to \infty$, denominator $\to 1$, so the limit is $\infty$

Comment: how do you get the answer without the rule? we are not allowed to use it yet

Comment: @Kaaagome I have added more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did divide by x^2, but I'm still confused how the numerator becomes infinity? I know that 1/x^2 = 0, but what about -x in the numerator?

Comment: @Kaaagome $-x\to \infty$, which means it can be larger that any positive number. Hence the numerator $\to \infty$. I think you may be not clear about the definition of $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$. It means $\for all M<0, \exists N\in \mathbb{R}$,s.t. $\forall x<-N, f(x)<M$. You can use this to check the numerator.

Comment: ah so you mean like u plugged in negative infinity for x? so infinity/1 = infinity. But if it was like infinity/2, would that still be infinity?

Comment: @Kaaagome There is a typo in above comment, it should be $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Kaaagome Yes. Please use the definition I gave above to check your statement.

Comment: thank you very much! but this is what I see in your definition explanation "\forallM<0,∃N∈R,s.t. ∀x<−N,f(x)<M"

Comment: @Kaaagome We say $\lim_{x\to −\infty}f(x)=−\infty$ if  $\forall M<0,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$,s.t. $\forall x <−N,f(x)<M$.